# mofify odp.net type mapping for C# DataSet

Tags: c#, oracle12c

How can I influence the process of generating a DataSet from a given table in a Oracle database such that a `number(5,0)` typed column in Oracle is mapped to a `int16` typed column in the dataset? By default the mapped column type is `int32`.

So far I tried to to extend my ***app.config*** with

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <edmMappings>
        <edmNumberMapping>
          <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="4" MaxPrecision="5" DBType="Number" />
        </edmNumberMapping>
      </edmMappings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

But I had no luck...

Thanks!